# PowerApps - If the user selects a value from the dropdown to navigate to a specific screen

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have completed all my screens in PowerApps and I am now trying to setup the navigation.

- My dropdown is named ***Dropdown1***
- The dropdown value in question is ***Employement***
- The screen that I want the user to go to if he/she selects *Employement* in the dropdown is called ***Section 3 Other Mirror***
- the screen that I want the user to go to if he/she selects any other choice in the dropdown is called ***Section 4 VP Setup***

Current formula:
`If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Employement"; Navigate('Section 3 Other Mirror',ScreenTransition.Cover)`

Error: **Unexpected characters. 'ParenClose' where 'Eof' is expected.**

Answer (score 1):

You can make a collection in the OnStart section with for example:

```
[
  {
     Name: "Employers",
     ScreenName: [@Screen1]
  },
  {
    Name: "Admins",
    ScreenName: [@Screen2]
  }
]
```

If you put this collection on a dropdown, you could use your navigate via the OnSelect of a button as follow:

```
Navigate( Dropdown.Selected.ScreenName, YourTransitionStyle )
```

Saves a lot of rewriting in lots of places.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to turn on the `OnSelect` in order to reach the values.

[image: Screenshot]